# Subset df where value is followed by a separate value - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Using below, I'm hoping to drop any rows that are equal to `X` that aren't directly followed by
`BKE` or `DKE` in the previous row. Furthermore, `Time` should be identical between `BKE`, `DKE` and `X`, otherwise `X` should also be dropped.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Time' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
    'Item' : ['A','BKE','X','Y','X','DKE','X','Y','X'],          
   })
```

df:

```
   Time Item
0     1    A
1     1  BKE
2     1    X # keep. X follows BKE and Time is identical
3     2    Y
4     2    X # drop. X doesn't follows BKE or DKE
5     2  DKE
6     3    X # drop. X follows BKE or DKE but Time is different
7     3    Y
8     3    X # drop. X doesn't follows BKE or DKE

df = df[(df['Item'] == 'X') & (df['Item'].isin(['BKE','DKE'])).shift(1)]
```

intended output:

```
   Time Item
0     1    A
1     1  BKE
2     1    X
3     2    Y
4     2  DKE
5     3    Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break your conditions down, for better readability (and to make inspection easier):

```py
is_prev_ke = df['Item'].shift(1).isin({'BKE', 'DKE'})
is_x = (df['Item'] == 'X')
prev_same_time = df['Time'] == df['Time'].shift(1, fill_value=True)

newdf = df.loc[~is_x | (is_x & is_prev_ke & prev_same_time)]
```

```
>>> newdf
   Time Item
0     1    A
1     1  BKE
2     1    X
3     2    Y
5     2  DKE
7     3    Y
```

Example of inspection:

```py
cond = ~is_x | (is_x & is_prev_ke & prev_same_time)
df.assign(is_prev_ke=is_prev_ke, is_x=is_x, 
          prev_same_time=prev_same_time, cond=cond)
```

Output:

```
   Time Item  is_prev_ke   is_x  prev_same_time   cond
0     1    A       False  False            True   True
1     1  BKE       False  False            True   True
2     1    X        True   True            True   True
3     2    Y       False  False           False   True
4     2    X       False   True            True  False
5     2  DKE       False  False            True   True
6     3    X        True   True           False  False
7     3    Y       False  False            True   True
8     3    X       False   True            True  False
```